# To "opt-out" or to "withdraw"?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary, formality

Which is more formal in register, ***opt-out of*** something or ***withdraw from*** something?

Are there any more formal ways to phrase the idea?

Comment: To opt out [of] means to choose not to be involved in. This can include to choose not to _get_ involved in. However, to withdraw from something requires that you are already involved, if only as a candidate.

Comment: Then what? Pulling out of sth?

Comment: Choose not to enter / get involved in/with vs Elect to leave / Quit / Leave ... There are many synonyms.

Comment: What is the context? In international law, for example, opting out is rather different from withdrawal when it comes to treaties.

Comment: "Withdrawal from/An opt-out of the project is the latest in a series of blows to industry reliant on high cost production struggling with oil prices at six-year lows."

Comment: [Companies] withdraw*ing* from the project... [Eligible participants] opt*ing* out of the project... [are] the latest in a series of blows to [an] industry reliant on high cost production [while it] struggle[s] with oil prices at six-year lows.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this stupid internet age, we have to opt out of a lot of horrible functions in search engines, etc. You are in them by default....

Answer (score 2):

For a formal register, I would say ...

> "I do not elect to participate"

or

> "I withdraw (from consideration, participation, etc.)

rather than opt-out.